# Custom annotation for method parameter

Tags: java, annotations

I am trying to validate a method parameter using custom annotation, but annotation validator is not getting invoked.

The annotation

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = FieldValidator.class)
public @interface ValidField {
    String message() default "Incorrect field.";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

The FieldValidator

```
public class FieldValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidField, String> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(final ValidField arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final String field, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        System.out.println("Called annotations successfully - "+ field);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Testing through the main method

```
 public void testAnnotation(@ValidField String q){
        System.out.println("inside testAnnotation..");
  }
    /************************* TESTING ****************************/
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test test= new Test();
        test.testAnnotation("sample");
```

Expected: Called annotations successfully - sample should be displayed in the console

Answer (score 1):

Okay, It was a mistake testing it by the main method.
`@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` says annotation will be available at runtime.

It was tested successfully by the service call when the server is running.